# Not able to add value to List of named tuple

Tags: c#, namedtuple

I have a named List of named tuple and from this function `OnEndCircularReferencesCalculation()`

I am trying to add value to named tuple but getting error message like : **'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Arg_ParamName_Name'**

Please tell me where I made the mistake in code. which line I need to change? Thanks

See my code:

```
private class CustomCalculationService : ICustomCalculationService
{
    private List<(string sheet, int rowindex, int columnindex)>  _ListOfCells;
    public List<string>? Sheets { get; set; }
    public List<(string sheet, int rowindex, int columnindex)>? ListOfCells { get { return _ListOfCells; } }
    
    public void OnEndCircularReferencesCalculation(IList<CellKey> cellKeys)
    {
        if (cellKeys.Count > 0)
        {
            if (_ListOfCells == null)
                _ListOfCells = new List<(string sheet, int rowindex, int columnindex)>();

            for (int r = 0; r <= cellKeys.Count - 1; r++)
            {
                _ListOfCells.Add((Sheets[cellKeys[r].SheetId].ToString(), cellKeys[r].RowIndex, cellKeys[r].ColumnIndex));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the error message give you the exact line number? If not, you can step through with a debugger to find the line that breaks.

Comment: This line throwing the error i saw during debug `_ListOfCells.Add((Sheets[cellKeys[r].SheetId].ToString(), cellKeys[r].RowIndex, cellKeys[r].ColumnIndex));`

Comment: So your problem is likely the value of `cellKeys[r].SheetId`. (BTW, `r < cellKeys.Count` is more standard than `r <= cellKeys.Count-1`).

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop instead

Comment: i found the problem guys. this line return 1  from `Sheets[cellKeys[r].SheetId` and Sheets has one element so 1 is wrong rather it should be 0. then code will work. thanks all for your time.

Comment: I guse Sheets is null becouse i don't see to initialize it and assign any value to it. this code: Sheets[cellKeys[r].SheetId]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, your code could more succinctly be:

```
private class CustomCalculationService : ICustomCalculationService
{ 
    public List<string>? Sheets { get; set; }
    public List<(string sheet, int rowindex, int columnindex)>? ListOfCells { get; } = new();
    
    public void OnEndCircularReferencesCalculation(IList<CellKey> cellKeys) =>
      ListOfCells.AddRange(cellKeys.Select(ck => (Sheets[ck.SheetId], ck.RowIndex, ck.ColumnIndex)));
   
}
```

- You don't need to ToString a string you get out of a list
- Making the list when you make the class means you can use an auto prop
- LINQ can turn your list of cellkey into tuple sand AddRange can consume it all in one

Answer (score 0):

**If you not have items in Sheets, or 'cellKeys[r].SheetId' > Sheets.Count You will receive this error.**

> 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
> of the collection. Arg_ParamName_Name

[image]

Comment: yes you are right. i fixed the error.

Comment: good. congratulation